# Cartesian list from two numeric arrays in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql

Trying to get a list of all possible combinations of 2 arrays passed in to a PostgreSQL, for example:

```
create function foobar(
    _foo varchar(250)[],
    _bar varchar(250)[] ) returns table
    (
    foo varchar(250),
    bar varchar(250)
    ) as $$
begin
    return query
    select distinct
        ???,
        ???
    from
        ??? cross join
        ???;
end;
$$ language plpgsql;
```

... so if I try:

```
select * from foobar('{"1", "2", "3", "4"}', '{"5", "6", "7", "8"}');
```

... I would get a result set looking something like this:

```
foo bar
1   5
1   6
1   7
1   8
2   5
2   6
...
```

what would that query look like?  It seems that PostgreSQL would support something like this, but I don't know how to ask in a searchable manner.

Thanks!

**UPDATE**
With Frank;s help, I was able to generate the query I was looking for.  As a standalone query, it looks like this:

```
select distinct
    foo, bar
from unnest(cast('{"1", "2", "3", "4"}' as varchar(250)[])) as foo
cross join unnest(cast('{"5", "6", "7", "8"}' as varchar(250)[])) as bar;
```

This comes up with exactly the result I was looking for.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
WITH foo(y) AS (
    SELECT unnest(a) FROM ( VALUES(ARRAY[1,2,3,4])) x(a) -- your input, first array
),
bar(y) AS (
    SELECT unnest(a) FROM ( VALUES(ARRAY[5,6,7,8])) x(a) -- second array
)
SELECT
    *
FROM
     foo CROSS JOIN bar
ORDER BY 
    foo.y, bar.y;
```

Comment: Thanks @FrankHeikens.  The `unnest()` was the big part I was missing.  I also wasn't aware PostgreSQL supported CTE's... that will be useful too.